# Cannot get my blackjack program to print a shuffled version of a deck

Tags: java, class, methods, return, blackjack

I've recently started trying to teach myself some basic Java. One of the first projects that I decided to work on was a simple blackjack program. I was creating a few basic structures for the game (I haven't done anything with the actual game component of the program yet) and I haven't been able to get my `shuffleDeck` method to return a value.

I've looked on a variety of internet sources and even cross referenced with some other functional blackjack programs, and I still can't find my error. When I run the main method, it should shuffle the deck and then print it out. Can someone please help? I have a card class, a deck class, and a main blackjack class. They are separate, but I lumped them all together here.

```
public class Card {

private String suit;
private String name;
private int value;


public Card(String nameOfCard, int gameValue,String nameOfSuit){    
    value = gameValue;
    suit = nameOfSuit;
    name = nameOfCard;
}

String getSuit(){

    return suit;
}

String getName(){

    return name;    
}

int getValue(){

    return value;
}


}


public class Deck {

private Card[] cardDeck;

public Deck(){

    cardDeck = new Card[52];
    cardDeck[0]= new Card("Two",2,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[1]= new Card("Three",3,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[2]= new Card("Four",4,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[3]= new Card("Five",5,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[4]= new Card("Six",6,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[5]= new Card("Seven",7,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[6]= new Card("Eight",8,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[7]= new Card("Nine",9,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[8]= new Card("Ten",10,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[9]= new Card("Jack",10,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[10]= new Card("Queen",10,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[11]= new Card("King",10,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[12]= new Card("Ace",11,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[13]= new Card("Two",2,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[14]= new Card("Three",3,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[15]= new Card("Four",4,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[16]= new Card("Five",5,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[17]= new Card("Six",6,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[18]= new Card("Seven",7,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[19]= new Card("Eight",8,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[20]= new Card("Nine",9,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[21]= new Card("Ten",10,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[22]= new Card("Jack",10,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[23]= new Card("Queen",10,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[24]= new Card("King",10,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[25]= new Card("Ace",11,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[26]= new Card("Two",2,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[27]= new Card("Three",3,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[28]= new Card("Four",4,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[29]= new Card("Five",5,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[30]= new Card("Six",6,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[31]= new Card("Seven",7,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[32]= new Card("Eight",8,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[33]= new Card("Nine",9,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[34]= new Card("Ten",10,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[35]= new Card("Jack",10,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[36]= new Card("Queen",10,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[37]= new Card("King",10,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[38]= new Card("Ace",11,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[39]= new Card("Two",2,"Spades");
    cardDeck[40]= new Card("Three",3,"Spades");
    cardDeck[41]= new Card("Four",4,"Spades");
    cardDeck[42]= new Card("Five",5,"Spades");
    cardDeck[43]= new Card("Six",6,"Spades");
    cardDeck[44]= new Card("Seven",7,"Spades");
    cardDeck[45]= new Card("Eight",8,"Spades");
    cardDeck[46]= new Card("Nine",9,"Spades");
    cardDeck[47]= new Card("Ten",10,"Spades");
    cardDeck[48]= new Card("Jack",10,"Spades");
    cardDeck[49]= new Card("Queen",10,"Spades");
    cardDeck[50]= new Card("King",10,"Spades");
    cardDeck[51]= new Card("Ace",11,"Spades");

}

public void shuffleDeck(){

    Card temp;
    int num;

        for(int k = 0;k<3000;k++)
        {   
            num = (int)Math.random()*52;
            temp = cardDeck[num];
            cardDeck[num]=cardDeck[0];
            cardDeck[0]=temp;
        }

    }

void printDeck(){

    for(int t = 0;t<52;t++){
        System.out.println(cardDeck[t].getName() + " of " + cardDeck[t].getSuit());
    }
        }
            }

public class BlackJack {

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    Deck cards = new Deck();
    cards.shuffleDeck();
    cards.printDeck();

        }
            }
```

Comment: Why do you think `shuffleDeck()` method needs to a) have a parameter b) return a value? Considering that you're calling the method on instance `cards` and also passing it `cards` as a parameter. That doesn't seem right, does it?

Comment: Consider using `Collections.shuffle()`

Comment: I'm pretty sure shuffleDeck returns a value.

Comment: Initially I did not use any parameters in that method. Last night when I was trying to figure out the issue, I tweaked it a few times. Here is what I initially thought it should look like. I'll edit it now

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing I see is that `(int)Math.random()*52` will always evaluate to 0. You basically generate a number between 0 and 1, cut off everything after the comma (by casting to int), so you always get a 0 which you then multiply by 52 to no effect.
You wanted `(int)(Math.random()*52)`. This way you first multiply and then cast. Even better, use the Random class to generate the number in the range you want, or better still, just do `Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cardDeck));` instead.

Comment: This way worked as well, thank you. I would have never caught that error myself. Being so new to java, I had never before used the Collections class, so I will definitely look into learning some of it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would try to use:

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(cardDeck));
```

instead of implementing shuffle method. Why re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that worked. Why did my previous method not work? @Lucas

Comment: @BryceMorrow Hard to say now since as-is post-edit it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Besides I'm not sure what do you mean by not working. You said that you can't make your method return value, and if you mean return in a Java way then it's not gonna return anything since you used void as return type...

Comment: Ha. Seems I was a minute too late in posting an answer. Still, it migh contain an explanation as to why your method failed to work.

Comment: Exactly. My answer will make it working, but @veggen explained why it didn't work, hence +1 from me :)

Comment: Both of your ways worked, thanks for the responses guys!

Answer (score 0):

It's failed on this line : `num = (int)Math.random()*52;` as you did immediately cast ! 
change it to `num = (int) (Math.random() * 52);`

Here is the fixed version :

```
public class Card {

private String suit;
private String name;
private int value;

public Card(String nameOfCard, int gameValue,String nameOfSuit){    
    value = gameValue;
    suit = nameOfSuit;
    name = nameOfCard;
}

String getSuit(){

    return suit;
}

String getName(){

    return name;    
}

int getValue(){

    return value;
}


}

 class Deck {

private Card[] cardDeck;

public Deck(){

    cardDeck = new Card[52];
    cardDeck[0]= new Card("Two",2,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[1]= new Card("Three",3,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[2]= new Card("Four",4,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[3]= new Card("Five",5,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[4]= new Card("Six",6,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[5]= new Card("Seven",7,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[6]= new Card("Eight",8,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[7]= new Card("Nine",9,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[8]= new Card("Ten",10,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[9]= new Card("Jack",10,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[10]= new Card("Queen",10,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[11]= new Card("King",10,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[12]= new Card("Ace",11,"Diamonds");
    cardDeck[13]= new Card("Two",2,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[14]= new Card("Three",3,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[15]= new Card("Four",4,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[16]= new Card("Five",5,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[17]= new Card("Six",6,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[18]= new Card("Seven",7,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[19]= new Card("Eight",8,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[20]= new Card("Nine",9,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[21]= new Card("Ten",10,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[22]= new Card("Jack",10,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[23]= new Card("Queen",10,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[24]= new Card("King",10,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[25]= new Card("Ace",11,"Hearts");
    cardDeck[26]= new Card("Two",2,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[27]= new Card("Three",3,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[28]= new Card("Four",4,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[29]= new Card("Five",5,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[30]= new Card("Six",6,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[31]= new Card("Seven",7,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[32]= new Card("Eight",8,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[33]= new Card("Nine",9,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[34]= new Card("Ten",10,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[35]= new Card("Jack",10,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[36]= new Card("Queen",10,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[37]= new Card("King",10,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[38]= new Card("Ace",11,"Clubs");
    cardDeck[39]= new Card("Two",2,"Spades");
    cardDeck[40]= new Card("Three",3,"Spades");
    cardDeck[41]= new Card("Four",4,"Spades");
    cardDeck[42]= new Card("Five",5,"Spades");
    cardDeck[43]= new Card("Six",6,"Spades");
    cardDeck[44]= new Card("Seven",7,"Spades");
    cardDeck[45]= new Card("Eight",8,"Spades");
    cardDeck[46]= new Card("Nine",9,"Spades");
    cardDeck[47]= new Card("Ten",10,"Spades");
    cardDeck[48]= new Card("Jack",10,"Spades");
    cardDeck[49]= new Card("Queen",10,"Spades");
    cardDeck[50]= new Card("King",10,"Spades");
    cardDeck[51]= new Card("Ace",11,"Spades");

}

public void shuffleDeck(){

    Card temp;
    int num;

        for(int k = 0;k<3000;k++)
        {   
            num = (int) (Math.random() * 52);
            temp = cardDeck[num];
            cardDeck[num]=cardDeck[0];
           cardDeck[0]=temp;

        }

    }

void printDeck(){

    for(int t = 0;t<52;t++){
        System.out.println(cardDeck[t].getName() + " of " + cardDeck[t].getSuit());
    }
        }
            }

public class BlackJack {

public static void main(String[] args){ 

    Deck cards = new Deck();
    cards.shuffleDeck();
    cards.printDeck();

        }
            }
```

[image]